# mat table multiple headers sticky not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat table with 2 headers in my 3rd and 4th column other columns I used rowspan, in which I need first 4 columns to be sticky. so  used sticky attribute. but when I scroll horizontally the second row header of 3rd and 4th columns are not sticky it also getting scrolled.

before horizontal scroll it looks like this

[image]

after scrolling horizontally it looks like this

[image]

I used **sticky** attribute in the  tag

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css code:

```html
.mat-header-row {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   background-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still Not working.